# Do filter-specific dyes exist? Equivalently, do dye-specific filters exist?

Tags: aqueous-solution, color, filtering

Apologies if this isn't chemistry enough for chemistry.se. I'm happy to go elsewhere if there are suggestions.

Blue + Red = Purple is arbitrary here. If any different colors might make this more feasible, please say so (preferably with some explanation as to why).

## I'm interested in having a jug of purple liquid.

When I turn it upside-down, it will empty through two bottlenecks into two smaller jugs. I would like for one of the smaller jugs to now contain red liquid, and the other to contain blue. Eg, I would like for one bottlenecks to actively filter out the red/blue portions of the original purple liquid.

## This process has to be repeatable.

That is, I should be able to turn this contraption back over on itself and the blue/red will recombine to be purple, and then for the separation of colors to happen again when it's flipped a third time. It's not very suitable for me if this system only works a few times before losing its punch, but it may be acceptable if I had to replace or clean filters once every 50 or 100 filtrations.

Looking forward to some affirmative answers, or even some suggestions on how to better search for this.

Comment: Can you give any context as to why you'd want to do this? As a classroom demonstration of actual science or for a different purpose?

Comment: I'd like to build one of these, but with color separation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAkMUdeB06o

Comment: Color has no direct importance in filtration and this question doesn't seem properly researched.

Comment: @Mithoron How about with the "illusion" of color filtration such as in the example of the YouTube video where those containers are clear mixed with blue liquid, you could have those be colored and the liquid be colored to just give this illusion rather than actually filtering out the chemicals, etc. within the liquid. In other words, a  "magic" trick, spooky... Boo!!!! Wahaa ha ha! Do some research on a magic trick of this nature and post back with an updated question with more detail. . . David Copperfield may be lurking around chimistry s.e. to provider further guidance. Hocus Pocus, kazam!!